# How to show loading gif while sending email?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a contact form with php, jquery, ajax its working fine but doesnt show mail sending process.
so people think it doesnt work and keep clicking send button again and again.

I want to show loading image while email sending.

Here is my form html I shortened it:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load-image').hide()
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#load-image').show();
        var name =$("#mail-name").val();
        var email =$("#mail-email").val();
        var subject =$("#mail-subject").val();
        var message =$("#mail-message").val();
        var captcha =$("#mail-captcha").val();
        var departman =$("#mail-departman").val();
        var submit =$("#mail-submit").val();
        $(".form-message").load("heads/contact.php",{
            name: name,
            email: email,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            captcha: captcha,
            departman: departman,
            submit: submit
        },function(){
            $('#load-image').hide();
            });
    });
});
```

```css
.load-image{
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form action="heads/contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" placeholder="Name..">  
    <br />
   <p class="form-message"></p>
    <br />
    <div id="load-image" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
    <img src="image/giphy.gif" width="31" height="31" alt="Loading image"/>
    </div>
    <br />
   <button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
```

I have tried this, but it showing loading image trough page load.

this is the code I injected in :

```
   `$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#mail-submit').submit(function(){
      $('#load-image').show();
});`
```

My total codes looks like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load-image').hide()
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#load-image').show();
        var name =$("#mail-name").val();
        var email =$("#mail-email").val();
        var subject =$("#mail-subject").val();
        var message =$("#mail-message").val();
        var captcha =$("#mail-captcha").val();
        var departman =$("#mail-departman").val();
        var submit =$("#mail-submit").val();
        $(".form-message").load("heads/contact.php",{
            name: name,
            email: email,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            captcha: captcha,
            departman: departman,
            submit: submit
        },function(){
            $('#load-image').hide();
            });
    });
});
```

> Here is my callback part of function:

```
$("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-subject, #mail-message, #mail-departman, #mail-captcha").removeClass("input-error");
var errorEmpty = "<?php echo $errorEmpty;?>";
var errorEmail = "<?php echo $errorEmail;?>";
if(errorEmpty == true){
    $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-subject, #mail-message, #mail-departman, #mail-captcha").addClass("input-error");
}
if(errorEmail == true){
    $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-subject, #mail-message, #mail-departman, #mail-captcha").addClass("input-error");
}
if(errorEmpty == false && errorEmail == false){
    $("#mail-name, #mail-email, #mail-subject, #mail-message, #mail-departman, #mail-captcha").val("");
}
```

Load-image css :

```
.load-image{
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Hide loading image by css or jQuery, then on form submit trigger it to show and after ajax complete hide it again

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#load-image').hide()
    $("form").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
  $('#load-image').show();
        var name =$("#mail-name").val();
        var email =$("#mail-email").val();
        var subject =$("#mail-subject").val();
        var message =$("#mail-message").val();
        var captcha =$("#mail-captcha").val();
        var departman =$("#mail-departman").val();
        var submit =$("#mail-submit").val();
        $(".form-message").load("heads/contact.php",{
            name: name,
            email: email,
            subject: subject,
            message: message,
            captcha: captcha,
            departman: departman,
            submit: submit
        },function(){
   $('#load-image').hide();
   });
    });
});
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 
<form action="heads/contact.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="mail-name" name="name" placeholder="Name...">
       <br />
     <img id="load-image" src="http://www.dabur.com/daburhonitus/images/preloader.gif" width="31" height="31" alt="Loading image" />
     <br />
     <p class="form-message"></p>
     <button id="mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: I tried your codes with image in div and css visibility but didnt show images on submiting form. and thanks for answer, your codes is added to my code in question and I turned your function hide to show is well `$('#load-image').show();`

Comment: please share your loading image css

Comment: css added to question

Comment: <div id="load-image" style="visibility: hidden;"/> remove visibility hidden from image warper OR in script also add css property to visibility hidden to visible

Comment: thanks bro it works fine now, I am wondering if I can use your image loader.gif ? :):)

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is correct, you need to show the loading image when the request starts and hide it again when the request completes. However to do that use the existing `submit` event handler on your form to show the image. You can also disable the button here to stop multiple clicks.

Then you can use the callback of `load()` to hide the image and re-enable the button again after the request finishes. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $loadImage = $('#load-image').show(); // show loading image
    var $mailSubmit = $('#mail-submit').prop('disabled', true); // disable the submit button
    
    $(".form-message").load("heads/contact.php", {
      name: $("#mail-name").val(),
      email: $("#mail-email").val(),
      subject: $("#mail-subject").val(),
      message: $("#mail-message").val(),
      captcha: $("#mail-captcha").val(),
      departman: $("#mail-departman").val(),
      submit: $("#mail-submit").val()
    }, function() {
      $loadImage.hide(); // hide loading image
      $mailSubmit.prop('disabled', false); // enable the submit button
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I have updated my code and added what you suggest but didnt show image on submit.